# cross origin request in web application

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, tizen, tizen-emulator

In my application for Tizen system, I make a cross origin AJAX request, it works well in Tizen's browser, but when I package it as web application, the cross origin request can't work. I've tested it both on emulator and real device.
I also use the webkit inspector record the network log, the screenshot is as following:
[image]

Could any expert tell me why?

The following is my code:

```
var url = "";//this is assigned a domain which supports cross domain access according to HTML5 specification.
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", url, true);
client.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", 'en-us');
client.onreadystatechange = function() { alert("succeed"); }
client.send();
```

Comment: set request header in server response

Comment: Yes, it has certainly been set. It works well in Tizen's browser.

Comment: if server and client is from different port or dopmain then cross orgin pblm will occur

Comment: @Parvathy, thank you. My code has run in browsers before, whatever the ports of server, it works well, server which accepts ajax request is configured to support cross origin request. but when I deploy my code as a web application run in local environment on Tizen device, it can't work.

Comment: @jasonjifly try the solution mentioned int the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any resource that it is accessed outside should be declared[(see Accessing External Network Resources):](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/app_dev_process/accessing_external_network_resources.htm)

> You cannot access external network resources by default (WARP: W3C
>   Access Requests Policy). So, you must request permissions for the
>   widget to retrieve network resources. You can enter several URLs by
>   using the Add button on the Access tab. For each URL, you can indicate
>   if you want to allow the widget to access the URL sub-domains. The
>   Allow subdomain column contents can be toggled by mouse clicks.

so it cannot work without having access to the specific resource needed in our case defined in `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="http://url_resource" subdomains="true"/>
```

or

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

to let everything pass.

Comment: It does works! Thank you very much! I've been stuck by it for two days, it really confused me a lot.